# Difference in Markdown between my profile and network profile

Tags: bug, profile-page, markdown, network-profile

My information on my regular profile currently looks like this:

[image]

But currently, my network profile looks like this:

[image]

Notice how the header "my network-wide stats" is less bolded than the other headers? It does similar things throughout my network profile vs. what it should look like from my regular profile.

Comment: It would be better to add a frame to those images. And/or some [(red) freehand circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775).

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q I've seen those before but I am unsure how to add them to my pictures. How do you do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Headers on stackexchange.com do not have any bolding (they are set to `font-weight: normal` in the CSS there).

The headers that are bold in your bio are that way because you manually bolded all those headers in the Markdown.

```
**Please upvote my helpful answers!  (on Writing SE, few people cast votes on answers)**
------------------------
```

The two that are not are not bolded in your Markdown.

```
My SE network-wide stats.
----------
```

You don't notice this difference in your Markdown because on the regular sites, headers are also bolded. Thus putting each header inside its own bold element achieves no visual difference. Bolding something already bold results in bold.

Comment: *Mind-Blowing!* I had no idea that was the case, thank you!